# Floating my icons to the right in my footer

Tags: css, html, footer

I have a problem..
I am trying to make my footer bar but it is not going very well.

The copyright logo, the year and my name are on the left and the social icons have to go to the right. I can't solve this problem! ;( I can't float it to the right.

If someone knows how it works, please react! :D

```css
footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  clear: both;
  background-color: #303030;
  color: #868686;
  position: relative;
}
footer span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 50px;
}
.footerwidth {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.icons {
  float: right;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<footer>

  <div class="footerwidth">
    <span>&copy 2016 Jasper Mulder
        <div class="icons">
        <a href="#"><img src="../images/icons/facebook.png"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="../images/icons/instagram.png"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="../images/icons/linkedin.png"></a>
        </div>
        </span>
  </div>

</footer>
```

Thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML and put the social icons before the copyright span:

```
<footer>
  <div class="footerwidth">
    <div class="icons">
        <a href="#"><img src="../images/icons/facebook.png"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="../images/icons/instagram.png"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="../images/icons/linkedin.png"></a>
    </div>
    <span>&copy 2016 Jasper Mulder</span>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your `.icons` div outside the `<span>` and also add `float: left` to the span:

```css
footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  clear: both;
  background-color: #303030;
  color: #868686;
  position: relative;
}
footer span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
}
.footerwidth {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.icons {
  float: right;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<footer>

  <div class="footerwidth">
    <span>&copy 2016 Jasper Mulder</span>
    <div class="icons">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="../images/icons/facebook.png">
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="../images/icons/instagram.png">
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="../images/icons/linkedin.png">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

</footer>
```

I also added `line-height: 50px;` as a little bonus ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, there are many solutions.

```
footer span {
position:relative;
top:15px;
left:-110px;
height: 50px;
}
```

Do not use table for layout.

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/BjdWWq

Answer (score 0):

css should be:

```
.footerwidth {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    PADDING-TOP: 15PX;
}
footer span {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
}
.icons {
    float: right;
    HEIGHT: 50PX;
    width: 150px;
}
```

HTML should be:

```
<div class="footerwidth">
    <span>© 2016 Jasper Mulder</span>
    <div class="icons">
        <a href="#"><img src="../images/icons/facebook.png"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="../images/icons/instagram.png"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="../images/icons/linkedin.png"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/9n4cav1o/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the `jsFiddle` for your problem. 
Please go through it.
https://jsfiddle.net/dhqp3Ln5/